# How does NSMutableData work?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have one problem to work with `NSMutableData`.

I defined one `NSMutableData *receivedData`, and tried to copy several `NSData*` data to the `receivedData`. I just called `[receivedData appendData:data]`, but appears the data is not copied:

```
....
NSLog(@"get data! Received %d bytes of data",[data length]);
  // output is not zero, say 1231.

[receivedData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"after append! length is %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
  // showing zero
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check if `receivedData == nil`. If so, then you might have forgotten to initialize it. For example:

```
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Then release it when you don't need it anymore:

```
[receivedData release];
receivedData = nil;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Originally I thought if it is nil, it will report error. Thanks so much.

Comment: In Objective-C it is legal to send messages to nil, so no error there.