# Strange issue in didReceiveData due to basicAuthentication

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, basic-authentication

I am facing an issue in basic authentication ,for which I am not able to understand the reason why this issue is there.
In basic authentication I am getting response code 200 i.e authentication successful,but sometime I am not getting response data properly in iOS application.
If I paste request url in browser(even in iPhone safari browser also), I am always getting the response.But why I am not always getting the response in iOS application.

I have gone through many other issues in google and stack overflow for example [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539745/strange-problem-with-appenddata-in-didreceivedata-method-of-nsurlconnection), but no luck.

My code is as below:

```
//in implemetation file
-(void)basicAuthentication{
    .
    .
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:authenticationUrl]; 

        NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", @"username",@"password"];  

        NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", loginString];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 
        [request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    myData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    }

    //Delegate method called when the connection receives data
    /*
     * Callback, called when ever there is more response data read
     */
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        [myData appendData:data];
    }

    //in .h file
    @interface TestConnectionManager : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>{
        id <TestConnectionManagerDelegate>delegate;
        NSMutableData *myData;
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced near about similar issue and I got an temporary solution which I am going to suggest. But I am not sure that how much this will be  helpful for your case.

I have putted log messages of data received inside `didReceiveData` method. If you can't put the received data you can take the log of data length.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"data:%d",[data length]);
    [myData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"myData:%d",[myData length]);
}
```